# Getting data from programmatically created UIPickerView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIPickerView` that was programmed manually so that I was able to add seconds. The `UIPickerView` lets you choose hours, minutes, and seconds. I am having a very hard time figuring out how to get the data from this picker so that I can store it. Can someone help me? All the ones that apple has pre made have attributes that you can easily call to get the value but since I am using my own I am not sure how to tackle it. Thanks!

my didSelectRow method

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSInteger hRow = [timerDurationPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSInteger mRow = [timerDurationPicker selectedRowInComponent:1];
    NSInteger sRow = [timerDurationPicker selectedRowInComponent:2];
}
```

Comment: You mean UIDatePicker or UIPickerView?

Comment: @zachstarnes - check my edited answer and replay me ..is it working for you or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get selected row after scrolling of `UIPickerView` is over. Then you need to add valueChanged event of `UIPickerView.`

```
[myPickerView addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And add method name is

```
-(void)valueChange:(UIPickerView *) picker
{
  NSLog (@"%@", [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES]); // set row and component value.
}
```

`pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent` is a delegate method that return  selected  row in component, here you need to set your row and component.

**EDITE:**

Try with following code

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    int hRow = [[arrayOfHour objectAtIndex:[timerDurationPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]] intValue];
    int mRow = [[arrayOfMinute objectAtIndex:[timerDurationPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]] intValue];
    int sRow = [[arrayOfSecond objectAtIndex:[timerDurationPicker selectedRowInComponent:2]] intValue];

    NSLog (@"%d", hRow);
    NSLog (@"%d", mRow);
    NSLog (@"%d", sRow);
}
```

Just put my suggestion - Use `UIDatePicker` ***(with time Mode)*** instead of using `UIPickerView`, It is very easy to manage, you does not need to take/manage array of hour, minute and second.

Comment: this gives me an error of `Bad receiver type 'NSInteger`(aka 'int')`

Comment: Again i edited check it. or change NSInteger to int.

Comment: make sure, are you using UIPickerView not UIDatePicker ?

Comment: I am using a UIPickerView

Comment: Have you array of value of hours, minutes and seconds ?? then use `int hRow = [[arrayOfHour objectAtIndex:[timerDurationPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]] intValue];` as soon.. defiantly it's working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can implement this delegate method.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
      //Do you stuff here.
}
```

It will fire when you select on the particular row in picker. For example, If you select on first component, You can get selected index for first. At the same time, you want to get index of other component means, you can use this method. `selectedRowInComponent:`.

Comment: so the uipicker view has three components one for hours another for minutes and another for seconds. Your not technically selecting a row your just scrolling and stopping on the desired time. Would I do the same thing?

Comment: If you select on first component, You can get selected index for first. At the same time, you want to get index of other component means, you can use this method. `selectedRowInComponent:`. See, you've to workaround for getting data.

Comment: I have update my question with the function so far. I have the rows I still dont get how to get the data from those rows.

Comment: How do you populate data to pickerview? follow same procedure to get data by these index.

Comment: im sorry I do not understand is there a specific function I need to call after I have the rows

Comment: Did you implement this method `- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component`?

Comment: I did now lol but I need it to return an integer not a string

Comment: Hello this delegate doesn't return anything to you, It will load picker via this delegate method, you've to give data to picker's row by returning string.

Comment: @iPatel If he's not assigned delegate method, how can he see data on pickerview?

Comment: all I want is the integer values from each row so I can do calculations with them. I am new to this so I need all the help I can get I apologize for not understanding how it works. The `titleForRow` returns a sting not an integer

Comment: What? `You can do calculations with them`? If you need more understanding about picker, spent some time and do some research. don't waste other's time.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the delegate and datasource for the UIPickerView. So, In delegate methods you can  get the actions from UIPickerView. Please refer this for more info : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html

**Selecting Rows in the View Picker**

- – selectRow:inComponent:animated:
- – selectedRowInComponent: